# What is the difference between blender render and cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Sorry noob question, I've been bouncing back and forth from different tutorials some are in cycles render and some are in blender render

can i ask what is the big difference?
by the looks i am stuck in one when i start to place textures? 
The first tut was a cup in cycles render, but then i picked up something else on blender render and i've been going that way for a while,
other tuts have been going that way anyway.
Which should i choose and i gather i will have to stick to it or re adjust all 'graphics'?
I've done a bit of searching for a definitive answer but can't find anything :D

I'm surprised there is no cycles render tag.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: thanks, in related questions/possible answers it would only come up with this for me:  What are the main differences between lamps in Cycles vs lamps in Blender Internal?.
:)

Comment: The Stack Exchange search engine isn't always that good, I found this by googling "difference between cycles and blender internal".

Comment: for lamps read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-are-the-differences-between-lamps-in-cycles-and-blender-internal