# How to change settings in nodes

Tags: mesh, materials, node-editor

[image: from this]

[image: to this]

I have looked for an answer for 2 hours now and I can't seem to have found the answer. 'd once found it but I've forgotten since it was a long while ago

Comment: What are you trying to do? What render engine do you want to use?

Comment: I'm more comfortable using the second image's nodes than the other one's. I can bearly handle myself on blender and when I oppened a new file the nodes had changed @Denis

Comment: On the top of the screen change from blender render to cycles render

Comment: It hasn't changed, any other ideas?

Comment: just restarted it and worked, thanks @Denis

Comment: The top image shows Blender Internal Render materials, the bottom one shows Cycles renders, both are completely different and non-interchangeable. If you wish to use Cycles nodes (the ones below) change the active render engine in the menu on the top header, and stick with it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-are-the-differences-between-lamps-in-cycles-and-blender-internal