# Blender 2.8: Where can I find light energy/intensity in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I'm a super blender noob. I'm a grand total of 2 days in, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I've looked online, and can't find an answer.

Lamp intensity/energy seems to have been removed from the Cycles renderer in Blender 2.8, and as far as I can tell, nothing replaced it. It still exists in the Eevee render.

Since 2.8 is a beta, I first assumed that maybe it was a bug, but the docs mimik this change by listing "energy" as an attribute of lamps in the Eevee renderer, and not listing it for cycles.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/lamps.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/lamps.html

I can't find any reference to "energy", "intensity", or "brightness" on the cycles page at all. BUT in the last section on Sun Lamps, in the last sentence, it does mention:

> Because they are not located inside the scene, their strength uses
>   different units, and should typically be set to lower values than
>   other lights.

So shouldn't that mean that there is the ability to modify it's strength somewhere?

I can find plenty of articles discussing functionality of 2.7x, but the only other reference I could find about 2.8 was a comment on an unrelated bug, where someone said that they can't find the intensity setting anymore, and that it was probably removed.

https://blenderartists.org/t/2-8-light-bleeding/1130700/4

Was light intensity deliberately removed from Cycles in 2.8? And if so, how do I increase the brightness of a Cycles sun lamp?

Thank you,

-Yurelle

**Update:**

I do not believe this is a duplicate of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81400/relation-between-bi-and-cycles-lamp-energy-emission-values). While that post does make a passing reference to the cycles lamp strength, this description is not explicit on where to find this option. Furthermore, it is unclear what version of blender it is referring to. That question was answered in June of 2017, nearly a full year before [Blender 2.8's first alpha](https://code.blender.org/2018/06/beyond-the-code-quest/) was [released (in June 2018)](https://80.lv/articles/the-release-date-of-blender-2-8-revealed/), which makes it unlikely this answer was referring to v2.8. Since the confusing change I am asking about was (as far as I can tell) introduced in v2.8, that makes the old answer insufficient; or at a bare minimum not clear in it's answer applying to the newly overhauled version. As I demonstrated in one of the links in my original question, this change is something which has confused others, not just myself. And, my question serves as an explicit target & solution to that confusion. @Mahmood ul Hassan's answer provides a direct, clear, & explicit answer to the nebulous question, without required other asker's to interpret passing remarks in unrelated questions on ambiguous software versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between BI and Cycles lamp energy/emission values?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81400/relation-between-bi-and-cycles-lamp-energy-emission-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select lamp, click on "use nodes". There will be "Strength" that you can change according to whatever you like. Which increases or decreases the intensity. Its default value is 100 I guess

Comment: The "Sun" type has "Strength", but the other types have "Power". What are the units for these lights?