# What units of intensity do Blender's lights use?

Tags: export, light

The "Sun" type has "Strength", but the other types have "Power". What are the units for these lights? Lumens? Lux? Candelas? They all default to 100, so maybe it's a percentage... of something? Does Strength use a different unit from Power?

I see there are already [other questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132903/blender-2-8-where-can-i-find-light-energy-intensity-in-cycles) asking about how they work specifically in Cycles, but in my use case I am making a scene in Blender and I want to export it to a game engine. I would like to know what units Blender uses for its lights so that I can perform a conversion where necessary, and verify the conversion is correct.

I also see [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149304/understanding-light-power-values) with an answer stating that it's in Watts, but they said that this is not the case from experimentation. I would like to know the true units, and how it is converted when exporting, and also I would like to know how to convert Blender's light units to lumens, lux, and/or candelas so that I can convert and verify.

EDIT: I am exporting to GLTF using Blender 2.83 beta. GLTF's light behavior is well documented: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_lights_punctual#light-shared-properties

Comment: Watts per square meter per steradian. Read: [What is the unit of measurement of light energy in Cycles?](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-unit-of-light-energy-attn-brecht/12456)

Comment: worth reading as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89877/how-does-blender-lights-work-in-cycles-regarding-intensity

Comment: Related: [Simulating a 40W Light Bulb](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180533/78972)