# Does it matter if I change from Blender render to Cycles and back?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm watching this tutorial series and can't figure out why the author always keeps it on cycles render instead of blender render.

What's the reason?

And what if I have blender render selected and make a change then switch to cycles and make a change then back to blender. While he always say has it on cycles? does that matter or?

Comment: Please use complete and descriptive titles

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal/5821 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/shader-nodes-are-missing/6832 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-are-the-differences-between-lamps-in-cycles-and-blender-internal/500